# Apache Test Page и auto deploy

Tags: centos, администрирование, tomcat, vps

На виртуальном сервере (`vps`) под `CentOS` работало приложение. Просто кидал свежую версию root.war в автодеплой директорию `webapps` и все работало. Произошел какой-то сбой (до конца не понял, судя по логам была превышена нагрузка на выделенные мощности) и vps перезагрузил. Теперь вижу тестовую страницу. Судя по логам war деплоится, но попытка перейти по портам прописанным в файлах конфигурации у меня не получается. Я только начинаю познавать суть администрирования, но чую своими силами буду копаться долго. В чем может быть причина и как исправить?

Comment: Вопрос всеобъемлющий, схож с трактовкой: А почему раньше работало, а сейчас - нет... Возможно будет закрыт).

Comment: если бы я знал причины и связи между этими причинами, то не обратился бы за помощью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat обычно не выставляется по 80 порту наружу, как правило работает он на 8080 или 8009 (AJP). Это, как все знают сервер приложений. Он обрабатывает и запускает всё, что написано в WAR разработчиком.

Вторая сторона - front-end, чаще apache (httpd) или nginx, который как раз и запускается и по 80 порту обслуживает клиентов. Обслуживание может заключаться в простом пропуске (реверс-прокси) траффика на порт 8080 (или 8009), и возврат ответа от Tomcat пользователю.

Теперь к сути вопроса: Вы видите Apache Test Page потому, что настройки виртуального хоста были изменены.

Ещё может быть, что модуль `mod_proxy`, используемый для реверс прокси не загружен (обновился и не работает), из-за чего не происходит связь Apache - Tomcat.

Просто так пальцем в небо тыкать плохо, поэтому приведите логи старта apache, вывод `netstat -anp` и `ps -aux`. Ну и если всё совсем плохо, пишите на почту, подскажу.

PS: А нагрузка на сервер скорее всего была именно 01-07-2015, скорее всего с 2 часов ночи, а версия CentOS - 6.3) Угадал?)

**UPD:** Добавлю конфигурацию mod_proxy_ajp

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from ::1
            Allow from 127.0.0.1
# Если нужно ограничение по IP адресам, то тут нужно поставить список разрешенных. Если ограничение не нужно - убрать всю секцию Proxy *
        </Proxy>

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyTimeout 300
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyVia On

        ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
        ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/

    </IfModule>
```

Comment: При оффлайн переписке с автором топика выяснили, что нет коннекта между httpd и tomcat, но порты 8080 и 8009 открыты, что говорит о неверной настройке apache.

Comment: помогло, спасибо большое